# Program output is incorrect

Tags: java

**Hey all, I'm currently in the midst of solving a problem, however after being stuck for over 2 weeks with no way out I have decided to turn to stack overflow.**

Problem:

A bus tour of Europe has been very successful. Due to an increase in the number of people that want to go on a tour, the tour company decided to increase the height of the bus. The new height of the bus is exactly N centimeters.

But the tour’s route runs under a lot of bridges, and there is a chance that the bus will crash into one of these bridges. Can you find out if this will happen?

The first line of the input contains the height of the bus and the number of bridges under which the bus passes. The second line contains the heights of these bridges.

You should output "Will not crash" if everything will be all right; otherwise, output "Will crash on bridge i" (where i is a number of a bridge) into which the bus will crash. If the height of a bridge equals the height of the bus, the bus will crash.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int busHeight = s.nextInt();
        int bridgeCount = s.nextInt();
        int bridgeHeight;
        boolean willCrash = false;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bridgeCount; i++) {
            bridgeHeight = s.nextInt();

            if (bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight) {
                willCrash = true;
                count++;
            }
            if (!(bridgeCount - count != 0 && willCrash)) {
                System.out.println("Will not crash");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + (bridgeCount - count));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input:
234 8
465 453 981 463 1235 871 475 981

Correct Output:
Will not crash

My output:
Will not crash

Sample input 2:
211 5
871 205 123 871 1681

Sample output:
Will crash on bridge 2

My Output:
Will not crash

Comment: *after being stuck for over 2 weeks* - What have you been doing for two weeks? Where is your debug code? Where do you display the values that you are testing to see if your test will work the way you expect? For example, for test 2, according to your input you should have 211 bridges, but you only provide heights for 6 bridges.

Comment: For example, for test 2, according to your input you should have 211 bridges, but you only provide heights for 6 bridges.

The first line of input is the bus height, and then the number of bridges. In test 2, the bus is 211cm high, and there are 5 bridges.

Comment: oops you area correct, I missed the ":" after the "2". I should use my glasses when reading a question. In any case you seemed to have missed the important part of my comment about doing basic debugging of your code to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your code step by step...

```
    ....

    for (int i = 0; i < bridgeCount; i++) {
        bridgeHeight = s.nextInt();
```

This makes sense!

```
        if (bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight) {
            willCrash = true;
            count++;
        }
```

1. You can cut out some of the extra work here by using the <= operator!
2. The number of bridges is not going to change. We should probably not be updating the count variable here.

   ```
        if (!(bridgeCount - count != 0 && willCrash)) {
            System.out.println("Will not crash");
            break;
   ```

It looks like you are still in your for loop! We can't know for sure that we won't crash until we get through all the other bridges.

```
        } else {
            System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + (bridgeCount - count));
            break;
        }
```

I am not sure why you decided to use bridgeCount - count as your bridge index. The i in the for loop we constructed should keep track of what bridge we are on!

Let's try and write some revised code:

```
for (int bridgeIndex = 0; bridgeIndex < bridgeCount; bridgeIndex++) {
   bridgeHeight = s.nextInt();
   
   if (bridgeHeight <= busHeight) {
     willCrash = true;
     // We know where our bus will crash. Let's abandon ship now!
     System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + bridgeIndex);
     break;
   }
} // end our for loop here!
if (!willCrash) {
   // We got through every element of the for loop and none of them caused a crash!
   System.out.println("Will not crash.");
}
```

Comment: Hey Anna,

thanks so much for replying with this help! I understand the question more now, and am going to test your code. I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

```
//we should start from 1 otherwise number 0 of the bridge is not correct
for (int bridgeIndex = 1; bridgeIndex <= bridgeCount; bridgeIndex++) {
   bridgeHeight = s.nextInt();
   
   if (bridgeHeight <= busHeight) {
     willCrash = true;
     // We know where our bus will crash. Let's abandon ship now!
     System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + bridgeIndex);
     break;
   }
} // end our for loop here!
if (!willCrash) {
   // We got through every element of the for loop and none of them caused a crash!
   System.out.println("Will not crash.");
}
```

Comment: If you don't know all details - why do write so insignificant message? This task is taken from https://hyperskill.org courses. I wrote variant that would pass - if=0 their compilation throw an error